# Extract Inline Data From Span With Parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

I want to be able to extract some data from an inline span but having trouble getting the data out.

Below is the section of code and I'm trying to get the **data-score="5"**. The number will change based on the customer review.

**Section of HTML:**

```
<span aria-label="5 star review" class="jdgm-rev__rating" data-score="5" tabindex="0">
```

The section of Python3 that someone helped me with can extract a class selector but want to get the data that is not a class.

**Partial Python Code:**

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(start_url).json()
    soup = bs(r['html'], 'lxml')
    ratings.extend([i.text for i in soup.select('.jdgm-rev__rating')])
    titles.extend([i.text for i in soup.select('.jdgm-rev__title')])
    total_pages = int(soup.select_one('.jdgm-paginate__last-page')['data-page'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is the span's attributes.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p><span aria-label="5 star review" class="jdgm-rev__rating" data-score="5" tabindex="0">')
>>> soup.find('span').attrs
{'aria-label': '5 star review', 'class': ['jdgm-rev__rating'], 'data-score': '5', 'tabindex': '0'}
>>> 
>>> int(soup.find('span').attrs['data-score'])
5
```

Comment: Will this work with the fact that the **data-score="5"** number will change from review to review? Here is the whole code. https://pastebin.com/1wEfLHsM